# IMPORTRANGE + QUERY won't import IMAGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I use Sheets in my business to create product catalogs for wholesale prices. I have different sheets for different companies but the data in many of them is the same. I'd like these sheets to sync from the main document. I've found a solution on here, however when I use the following function, the image imported in the main sheet using the IMAGE function doesn't get imported:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("key","All!A2:M130"),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 contains 'Home&Beauty&Fashion'")
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `ImportRange`; the issue can be reproduced using `Query` within the same sheet. The [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) explains that `Query`  only supports

> boolean, numeric (including date/time types) or string values.

As far as `Query` is concerned, an image contained in a spreadsheet is simply a null value.

A workaround is to store URL strings themselves in the master sheet. These can be retrieved by `Query`, and then `Image` can be applied to the result.